# Sequelize.js: how to handle reconnection with MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I've always used Mongo with Node, but now due to an existing datasource I need to connect a node app with Mysql.

Sequelize seems a good solution, but I don't get how to handle connection error, reconnection and re-tries.

To check for connection error on first run `.authenticate().then().catch(function(error){...});`
But what if I loose connection and want to reconnect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open issue for this in Sequelize:

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2113

Based on that, this error is handled in sequelize.

Comment: what do you mean with "this error is handled in sequelize"?

Comment: If the connection is lost, the lib will reconnect automatically.

Comment: that's great! How I could test it stopping mysql server while the app is running? Will it automatically log something? Thanks for help!

Comment: It is a good question, actually I don't know. :D But yeh, restart the sql server is a good test case. :)

Answer (score 3):

I verified the version 4.11.1 of sequelize has this issue fixed.
The queries will fail when the database server is down, but will recover to reconnect and succeed when the database server is up.
(You don't need to restart the application as faced with previous versions.)

Comment: Did you need to add custom retry options to the Sequelize instance? Looking at the source for sequelize it looks like it will only retry on `SQLITE_BUSY: Database is locked` errors by default.

Comment: I didn't use any custom retry option.

`var seqDb = new Sequelize(config.dbUri, { operatorsAliases: false });
module.exports = seqDb;
seqDb.sync()
.then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to DB...');
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log('Error connecting to DB: ' + err.message);
});`